# RabbitMQ error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value in table

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am upgrading my application from SpringBoot 1.5 to 2.3 and the following rabbitmq code section throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value in table`

Code snippet

```
private ProcessorDefinition<RouteDefinition> sendMessage() {
   return from("direct:publish-message").routeId("SendMessage")
          .to("{{rabbitmq.producer.endpoint}}");
}
```

Producer endpoint configured in application.properties as below

```
rabbitmq.producer.endpoint = rabbitmq://${spring.rabbitmq.host}/${exchangeName}?BridgeEndpoint=true&queue=${producerQueueName}&autoDelete=false&declare=true&routingKey=${routingKey}&exchangeType=topic&connectionFactory=#connectionFactory
```

The error

```
ERROR SendMessage - ID-IN-00500980-1227984484357-0-4 >>> Exception , java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value in table
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.fieldValueSize(Frame.java:310)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.arraySize(Frame.java:321)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.fieldValueSize(Frame.java:302)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.tableSize(Frame.java:250)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ValueWriter.writeTable(ValueWriter.java:119)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ContentHeaderPropertyWriter.writeTable(ContentHeaderPropertyWriter.java:97)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP$BasicProperties.writePropertiesTo(AMQP.java:1848)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQContentHeader.writeTo(AMQContentHeader.java:50)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQContentHeader.toFrame(AMQContentHeader.java:78)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:107)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:455)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:428)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:710)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicPublish(AutorecoveringChannel.java:207)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessagePublisher.publishToRabbitMQ(RabbitMQMessagePublisher.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessagePublisher.publish(RabbitMQMessagePublisher.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.publishExchangeToChannel(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:209)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer$2.doWithChannel(RabbitMQProducer.java:288)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer$2.doWithChannel(RabbitMQProducer.java:285)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.execute(RabbitMQProducer.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.basicPublish(RabbitMQProducer.java:285)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.processInOnly(RabbitMQProducer.java:272)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.process(RabbitMQProducer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:134)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultInstrumentationProcessor.process(DefaultInstrumentationProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryState.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:476)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:193)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

Can anyone suggest what is causing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is passed in the headers. In my case, the problem was in the header `CamelCxfMessage`.